# syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Tags: php

I've got a syntax error on my foreach. I want to select from my backoffice a text file which write all eamil from site. I want to only get email from my database and put them into a text file write in my hard disk.

```
<?php
    if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
        exit;

    class SuperModule extends Module
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->name = 'supermodule';
            $this->tab = 'administration';
            $this->version = 1.0;
            $this->author = 'Lelu Matthias';
            $this->need_instance = 0;
            $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
            $this->bootstrap = true;
            parent::__construct(); 
            $this->displayName = $this->l('My super module');
            $this->description = $this->l('This module is super !'); 
            $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
            if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))
                $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided.'); 
        }
        public function install()
        {
            if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
                Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
            return parent::install() &&
                $this->registerHook('displayNav') &&
                $this->registerHook('header') &&
                Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'super module') &&
                    Configuration::updateValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS', 'Ouvert de 9h a 19h') && Configuration::updateValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER', '0');
        }
        public function uninstall()
        {
            return parent::uninstall();
        }
        public function getContent()
        {
            $output = null;
            if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_openinghours'))
            {
                $supermodule_openinghours = Tools::getValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS');
                if (!$supermodule_openinghours  || empty($supermodule_openinghours) || !
                    Validate::isGenericName($supermodule_openinghours))
                    $output .= $this->displayError( $this->l('Invalid Configuration value') );
                else
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS', 
                                               $supermodule_openinghours);
                    $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
                }
            }
            if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_exportnewsletter'))

            {   
                $id_option = Tools::getValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER');
             $output .=$id_option;
                $txt="";
                if($id_option ==1)
                {
                    (foreach $newsletter as $row)
                    {
                    $text.=$row['email'];}
                    $table='newsletter';

                }
                else 
                {
                    (foreach $customer as $row)
                    {
                    $text.=$row['email'];
                    }
                    $table='customer';
                }

                $date = gmdate('dmY');
                $file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/export-newsletter-'.$table.'-'.
                              $date.'.txt', 'w');
                fputs($file, $txt);
                fclose($file);

            }
            return $output.$this->displayForm1().$this->displayForm2();
        }
        public function displayForm1()
        {
            $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

            $fields_form[0]['form'] = $this->formulaire1();

            $helper = new HelperForm();

            // Module, token and currentIndex
            $helper->module = $this;
            $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
            $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
            $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

            // Language
            $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
            $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

            // Title and toolbar
            $helper->title = $this->displayName;
            $helper->show_toolbar = true;
            $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;
            $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
            $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
                'save' =>
                array(
                    'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
            'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->
                    name.'&save'.$this->name.
                    '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                ),
                'back' => array(
                    'href' => AdminController::
                    $currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                    'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
                )
            );

            // Load current value
            $helper->fields_value['MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS'] = 
                Configuration::get('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS');
            return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
        }
        protected function formulaire1()
        {
            return array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Opening hours'),
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Opening hours'),
                        'name' => 'MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS',
                        'size' => 20,
                        'required' => true
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'name' => 'submit_openinghours',
                    'title' => $this->l('Save')
                )
            );
        }
        protected function formulaire2()
        {
            $options = array(
                array(
                    'id_option' => 0, 
                    'name' => $this->l('Customer table')
                ),
                array(
                    'id_option' => 1,
                    'name' => $this->l('Newsletter table')
                ),
            );
            return array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Newsletter export'),
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'label' => $this->l('Choice a table'),
                        'name' => 'MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Please choice a table.'),
                        'options' => array(
                            'query' => $options, 
                            'id' => 'id_option', 
                            'name' => 'name'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'submit' => array(
                            'name' => 'submit_exportnewsletter',
                            'title' => $this->l('Save')
                    )
            );
    }
        public function displayForm2()
        {
            $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

            $fields_form[0]['form'] = $this->formulaire2();

            $helper = new HelperForm();

            // Module, token and currentIndex
            $helper->module = $this;
            $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
            $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
            $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

            // Language
            $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
            $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

            // Title and toolbar
            $helper->title = $this->displayName;
            $helper->show_toolbar = true;  
            $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;  
            $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
            $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
                'save' =>
                array(
                    'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
    'href'=>AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.
                    '&save'.$this->name.
                    '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                ),
                'back' => array(
                    'href' => AdminController::
                    $currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                    'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
                )
            );
            // Load current value
            $helper->fields_value['MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER'] = 
                Configuration::get('MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER');
            return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
        }
        public function hookDisplayNav($params)
        {
            $ma_variable = Configuration::get('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS');
            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'ma_variable' => $ma_variable
            ));
            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'supermodulenav.tpl');
        }
        public function hookDisplayHeader()
        {
            $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/supermodule.css', 'all');
        }
        public function GetMailNewsLetter()
        {
            $sql='SELECT email FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'newsletter';
            $newsletter=Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
            return $newsletter;
        }
        public function GetMailCustomer()
        {
            $sql='SELECT email FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer';
            $customer=Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
            return $customer;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps using the right syntax: `foreach ($customer as $row)` instead of `(foreach $customer as $row)`

Comment: Please don't just copy and paste the whole code, but rather just post the necessary code parts for others to answer your question. Otherwise everyone trying to help you has to go through all the code to find your problem

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
foreach ($newsletter as $row)
```

Check the [Manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

Hey only change your `(foreach $newsletter as $row)` to `foreach($newsletter as $row)`

something like this

```
<?php
    if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
        exit;

    class SuperModule extends Module
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->name = 'supermodule';
            $this->tab = 'administration';
            $this->version = 1.0;
            $this->author = 'Lelu Matthias';
            $this->need_instance = 0;
            $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
            $this->bootstrap = true;
            parent::__construct(); 
            $this->displayName = $this->l('My super module');
            $this->description = $this->l('This module is super !'); 
            $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
            if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))
                $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided.'); 
        }
        public function install()
        {
            if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
                Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
            return parent::install() &&
                $this->registerHook('displayNav') &&
                $this->registerHook('header') &&
                Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULE_NAME', 'super module') &&
                    Configuration::updateValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS', 'Ouvert de 9h a 19h') && Configuration::updateValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER', '0');
        }
        public function uninstall()
        {
            return parent::uninstall();
        }
        public function getContent()
        {
            $output = null;
            if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_openinghours'))
            {
                $supermodule_openinghours = Tools::getValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS');
                if (!$supermodule_openinghours  || empty($supermodule_openinghours) || !
                    Validate::isGenericName($supermodule_openinghours))
                    $output .= $this->displayError( $this->l('Invalid Configuration value') );
                else
                {
                    Configuration::updateValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS', 
                                               $supermodule_openinghours);
                    $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
                }
            }
            if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_exportnewsletter'))

            {   
                $id_option = Tools::getValue('MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER');
             $output .=$id_option;
                $txt="";
                if($id_option ==1)
                {
                    foreach ($newsletter as $row)
                    {
                    $text.=$row['email'];
                    }
                    $table='newsletter';



                }
                else 
                {
                    foreach ($customer as $row)
                    {
                    $text.=$row['email'];
                    }
                    $table='customer';
                }

                $date = gmdate('dmY');
                $file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/export-newsletter-'.$table.'-'.
                              $date.'.txt', 'w');
                fputs($file, $txt);
                fclose($file);

            }
            return $output.$this->displayForm1().$this->displayForm2();
        }
        public function displayForm1()
        {
            $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

            $fields_form[0]['form'] = $this->formulaire1();

            $helper = new HelperForm();

            // Module, token and currentIndex
            $helper->module = $this;
            $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
            $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
            $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

            // Language
            $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
            $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

            // Title and toolbar
            $helper->title = $this->displayName;
            $helper->show_toolbar = true;
            $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;
            $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
            $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
                'save' =>
                array(
                    'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
            'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->
                    name.'&save'.$this->name.
                    '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                ),
                'back' => array(
                    'href' => AdminController::
                    $currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                    'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
                )
            );

            // Load current value
            $helper->fields_value['MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS'] = 
                Configuration::get('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS');
            return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
        }
        protected function formulaire1()
        {
            return array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Opening hours'),
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Opening hours'),
                        'name' => 'MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS',
                        'size' => 20,
                        'required' => true
                    ),
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'name' => 'submit_openinghours',
                    'title' => $this->l('Save')
                )
            );
        }
        protected function formulaire2()
        {
            $options = array(
                array(
                    'id_option' => 0, 
                    'name' => $this->l('Customer table')
                ),
                array(
                    'id_option' => 1,
                    'name' => $this->l('Newsletter table')
                ),
            );
            return array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Newsletter export'),
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'label' => $this->l('Choice a table'),
                        'name' => 'MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER',
                        'desc' => $this->l('Please choice a table.'),
                        'options' => array(
                            'query' => $options, 
                            'id' => 'id_option', 
                            'name' => 'name'
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'submit' => array(
                            'name' => 'submit_exportnewsletter',
                            'title' => $this->l('Save')
                    )
            );
    }
        public function displayForm2()
        {
            $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');

            $fields_form[0]['form'] = $this->formulaire2();

            $helper = new HelperForm();

            // Module, token and currentIndex
            $helper->module = $this;
            $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
            $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
            $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

            // Language
            $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
            $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

            // Title and toolbar
            $helper->title = $this->displayName;
            $helper->show_toolbar = true;  
            $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;  
            $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
            $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
                'save' =>
                array(
                    'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
    'href'=>AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.
                    '&save'.$this->name.
                    '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                ),
                'back' => array(
                    'href' => AdminController::
                    $currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                    'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
                )
            );
            // Load current value
            $helper->fields_value['MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER'] = 
                Configuration::get('MOD_SUPERMODULE_NEWSLETTER');
            return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
        }
        public function hookDisplayNav($params)
        {
            $ma_variable = Configuration::get('MOD_SUPERMODULE_OPENINGHOURS');
            $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'ma_variable' => $ma_variable
            ));
            return $this->display(__FILE__, 'supermodulenav.tpl');
        }
        public function hookDisplayHeader()
        {
            $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/supermodule.css', 'all');
        }
        public function GetMailNewsLetter()
        {
            $sql='SELECT email FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'newsletter';
            $newsletter=Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
            return $newsletter;
        }
        public function GetMailCustomer()
        {
            $sql='SELECT email FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'customer';
            $customer=Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
            return $customer;
        }
    }
```

I think it help you

Answer (score 1):

> You are using wrong **foreach** syntax.follow the given below code.also check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

```
(foreach $newsletter as $row)   // it is not a correct syntax
foreach ($newsletter as $row)   // this is a correct syntax

(foreach $customer as $row)   // it is not a correct syntax
foreach ($customer as $row)   // this is a correct syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

wrong syntax:

```
(foreach $newsletter as $row)
```

Correct Syntax

```
foreach($newsletter as $row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of `foreach` is

```
foreach($newsletter as $row)
{

}
```

Not

`(foreach $newsletter as $row)`